# File based database in Java

Tags: java, database

Are there any libraries create programs in java that uses a file as a database and you don't have to install database services on the computer you are going to use it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) and Hypersonic SQL can both be run in memory and server modes.

Comment: +1. This should be the answer, not sqlite which requires platform specific libraries. Just add some links: 
http://db.apache.org/derby/ 
http://hsqldb.org/ 
http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Answer (score 18):

What about [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)?

> H2 is a relational database management system written in Java. It can be embedded in Java applications or run in the client-server mode. The disk footprint (size of the jar file) is about 1 MB. (Wikipedia)

Answer (score 8):

there is a very good java binding for [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) databases called SqliteJDBC:

http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/

Answer (score 7):

We are successfully using http://www.sqlite.org/ along with http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/ as JDBC driver.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone looks for a **very simple file based database** try this older [low-level database](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-01-1999/jw-01-step.html) which is very easy to understand. It is a tutorial, but you can download the full source code [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-01-1999/step/jw-01-step.zip).

Basically it uses a simple RandomAccessFile and standard java serialization, so you can store everything serializable and you don't need any special configuration or Annotations in your objects to use it. No need for any libraries.

Answer (score 4):

> MapDB provides concurrent Maps, Sets and Queues backed by disk storage or off-heap-memory. It is a fast and easy to use embedded Java database engine.

https://github.com/jankotek/MapDB

http://www.mapdb.org/

Comment: Among key-value stores, [Chronicle Map](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Map) and [JetBrains Xodus](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/) are also strong alternatives (see [performance comparison, including MapDB](http://jetbrains.github.io/xodus/#benchmarks))

Comment: I just want to add that MapDB (and its dependencies) is quite big. It adds around 14.5 MB to a runnable JAR file.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the already mentioned embedded relational databases, there are also non-relational embedded Java databases like [exist](http://exist.sourceforge.net/) (an XML DB) or [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) (an object DB).

Answer (score 2):

For example [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) or [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) can run in Embedded mode.

Answer (score 2):

Derby can run in the Embedded mode as mentioned above. It actually is included in Java 6 SE and called Java DB instead (although it is really just Apache Derby). It is quite easy to use, although the default database tool (ij) isn't great. I would use something like SQuirreL SQL to view the data.