# How would I compile a Java application including multimedia?

Tags: java, compilation, media

I wish to compile my java project in eclipse but I am at a loss and I can't figure out how to include my pictures and my database in the project or how to compile them all into one .jar file. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I figured out how to compile the java file into a jar file (here is the instructions for when using Eclipse: [link](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/12/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what Bruno said. If you're using eclipse to build/package your project then:

- add resources subfolder to project root folder
- right click project -> properties -> java build path and in source tab add the folder you just created.

Comment: Your answer helped me the most

Answer (score 1):

You can load data from `InputStream`s obtained from the classloader (using data on the classpath, possibly in a jar) instead of a `FileInputStream` (assuming that's what you do) as described here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/lang/resources.html

For the database, it will depend on whether the database engine you're using can load from the classpath. This method doesn't allow you to write, and some database engines may require write access for locking (depending on what you do with the DB).

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to programming in general so your help and wise words were wasted on me :/ sorry

Comment: No problem. The other answers talk about putting the resources on the classpath within Eclipse. My answer was more about using them from your Java application once they're on the classpath (either from your dev. environment in Eclipse, or from the bundled jar).

Comment: Is this the only way to include a SQL database in my .jar file?

Comment: For the SQL DB, it would depend on which one you're using (e.g. Derby, HSQLDB, ...). HSQLDB seems to have a [jdbc:hsqldb:res:](http://hsqldb.org/doc/src/org/hsqldb/jdbc/jdbcConnection.html) prefix for that.

Comment: I am currently using jdbc:mysql:localhost:3306 but as far as I know the database won't be accessible from other computers using this reference and I need it to be accessible :/

Comment: You'd need to move towards [a file-based Java DB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575451/file-based-database-in-java) (Derby, HSQLDB or other), or install MySQL on the machine where you deploy your application. Note that if you also load the DB from within the jar file directly, it will be read-only, otherwise you'll need to set up a writeable location where to install the DB files.

Answer (score 1):

Any file/directory you copy under the `/src` of your eclipse project will be included in the `jar` file created by eclipse and will be accessible from the java programs of that project as classpath resources.

Comment: Your answer helped but I was only able to fully succeed with soulchecks help